# LARAVEL how to change $fillable in Model from trait?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have in model:

```
use seoTrait;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'title', 'description'
];
```

I created trait "seoTrait" which need "seoMeta" in $fillable.

Now I add :

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'title', 'description', 'seoMeta'
];
```

But is it possible in trait "seoTrait" add something to $fillable ?

Comment: You can't overload a class attribute with a trait.

Comment: Hey Fico, answer you marked is correct is not working because of you can access $this from static context, could you please check my answer that should be correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.7, you can initialize a model trait with a magic `initializeTraitName` method on the trait which allow access to the model instance.

```php
trait SeoTrait
{
    public function initializeSeoTrait()
    {
        $this->fillable[] = 'seoMeta';
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this soon.

Comment: @PeterPan666 Hower are you able to use $this in a static function? I am getting error `Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: Method is being called, but you can access $this from static context.

Comment: Just use constructor: public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->fillable[] = 'seoMeta';
    } it works...

Comment: @fico7489 is right, you can just use a constructor and it seems to work.

Comment: You can't use `__construct()` on the trait because it overrides the model constructor.

Comment: So what's the solution

Comment: @Emil soluction is to use constructor but you have to accept attributes and pass them to parent constructor, please check my answer...

Comment: @PeterPan666 as my answer to this issue is now the most upvoted, could you add a mention to it in your answer?

Comment: @BrynJ I've commented your answer

Answer (score 23):

For anyone that came here looking for an answer; I believe that there is a better way than constructor overloading.

Others have pointed out that Laravel supports bootable model traits, using the `boot<TraitName>` method you can set up the trait for usage. However, the `boot<TraitName>` method has to be static, so you cannot alter any non-static properties of the model.

However, I found out that there is a non-static equivalent to the `boot<TraitName>` method; **the `initialize<TraitName>` method.**

Internally, when Eloquent boots up a model, it also registers all initialize methods for the model, based on the methods found in the traits that the model uses. Then upon instantiating that model, the initialize methods are fired.

An example of usage, based on the problem stated in this question:

```php
trait SEOTrait
{
    /**
     * This method is called upon instantiation of the Eloquent Model.
     * It adds the "seoMeta" field to the "$fillable" array of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeSEOTrait()
    {
        $this->fillable[] = 'seoMeta';
    }
}
```

Sadly there isn't any information in the official documentation about either bootable or initializable traits. However, I still find it really cool that both functionalities exist.

Comment: FYI this doesn't seem to be available in 5.5. At least, I'm trying it and it's simply not running.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as stated in the EDIT 2 in the "correct" answer

Answer (score 10):

I had the same requirement. However, I didn't want to declare a constructor in my trait, as this leads to very unexpected behaviour - what if another trait also declares a constructor?

As pointed out by PeterPan666, we can't use the static trait `boot()` method to directly set the non-static `fillable` property - but we can utilise [Laravel Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events), which receive an instance of the model.

For example:

```
public static function bootSeoTrait() : void
{
    static::retrieved(function($model) {
        $model->fillable = array_merge($model->fillable, ['seoMeta']);
    });
}
```

**Update**

Although the `$fillable` property is protected, the `GuardsAttributes` trait - which the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` uses - contains the following setter:

```
/**
 * Set the fillable attributes for the model.
 *
 * @param  array  $fillable
 * @return $this
 */
public function fillable(array $fillable)
{
    $this->fillable = $fillable;

    return $this;
}
```

So, we can set the `$fillable` protected property from our model instance in the `retrieved` event.

Comment: Sadly, `$fillable` is a protected attribute and cannot be accessed with `retrieved`

Comment: @PeterPan666 have you tested this? I have this solution working fine (Laravel 5.5 app).

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor inside your trait, but it is important to send fillable attributes to parent constructor Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Modal

```
    parent::__construct($attributes);
```

Here is example code:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->fillable[] = 'seoMeta';
}
```

Comment: Declaring a constructor in a trait is not generally recommended behaviour and, due to their nature, you couldn't have multiple traits with constructors being used in the same class. See my answer for an alternative approach

Answer (score 1):

As @DokiCRO said, you could implement a constructor within your trait. You must then consider that there won't be any other trait that will be able to overwrite the construct.

For anything else, I would suggest to go with the static bootTraitClassName(). But in this specific case we need to overwrite a non-static protected property, which can't be achievable within a static context.

So this justifies the constructor overload. Maybe use one trait that is responsible for overloading $fillable arrays for all your models, which will make your life easier in the long run.

Just make sure to include your code before the parent construct gets called though.

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
    $this->fillable[] = 'seoMeta';

    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622923/laravel-how-to-change-fillable-in-model-from-trait/49410537#49410537) using model events to achieve the desired result, without having to worry about overridden constructures

Comment: Although more elegant, your solution didn't work in my case... So I have to stick with the constructor overload. I'm using Laravel 5.6

Comment: That is interesting. I wonder what changed from 5.5 to 5.6? Could you try explicitly using the `fillable()` method in the `GuardsAttributes` trait? E.g. `$model->fillable(array_merge($model->fillable, ['seoMeta']));`?

Answer (score 1):

Example trait for Models with "active" column

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait CanActiveTrait
{
    /**
     * Scope a query to only include active model.
     */
    public function scopeActive(Builder $query): void
    {
        $query->where('active', true);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize trait on the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeCanActiveTrait(): void
    {
        $this->mergeCasts(['active' => 'bool']);
        $this->mergeFillable(['active']);
    }
}
```