# In Laravel, how can I boot trait non-statically

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, traits

Is there any reason why we only have this static way to boot traits in Laravel:

```
static function bootMyTrait ()
{...}
```

Is there any way to boot trait and have model instance in the boot function? Like this:

```
function bootMyTrait ()
{
    if ($this instanceOf awesomeInterface)
    {
        $this->append('nice_attribute');
    }
}
```

I need this AF, and for a very long time haven't found any solution.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I for one can't work out what you're asking.

Comment: @JonStirling Oh sorry, there were problems and typos in the question. Fixed them. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LARAVEL how to change $fillable in Model from trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622923/laravel-how-to-change-fillable-in-model-from-trait)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since [Laravel 5.7](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/627a305304c1e466cb3ce7904c19f7a2155bc7d2) you can use trait *initializers*, instead of trait *booters*. I've had the same task and was able to solve it like this:

```
public function initializeMyTrait()
{
    if ($this instanceOf awesomeInterface)
    {
        $this->append('nice_attribute');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, no one seems to care :D

Good news, is that within 15 min, I've solved my problem with this in *base model*:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{

    foreach (class_uses_recursive($this) as $trait)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, $method = 'init'.class_basename($trait))) {
            $this->{$method}();
        }
    }

    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

**Edit**

Instead of relying on traits for this, use Eloquent's accessors and mutators. For example, define the following methods on a `User` model:

```
// Any time `$user->first_name` is accessed, it will automatically Uppercase the first letter of $value
public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    return ucfirst($value);
}
```

This appends the `$user->first_name` attribute to the model. By prefixing the method name with `get` and suffixing it with `Attribute` you are telling Eloquent, Hey, this is an actual attribute on my model. It doesn't need to exist on the table.

On the other hand you can define a mutator:

```
// Any string set as first_name will automatically Uppercase words.
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['first_name'] = ucwords($value);
}
```

This will apply anything you do to `$value` before setting it in the `$attributes` array.

Of course, you can apply these to attributes that do exist on your database table. If you have raw, unformatted data, say a telephone number 1234567890, and you wanted to apply a country code, you could use an accessor method to mask the number without modifying the raw value from the database. And going the other way, if you wanted to apply a standard formatting to a value, you could use a mutator method so all your database values conform to a common standard.

[Laravel Accessor and Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#introduction)

Comment: I'm curious, what's the use case for needing it in a non static context?

Comment: @btl If you look at my question, you can see exact use case: appending attribute to eloquent. If you are not in Laravel too much, then in plain PHP use case may be adding necessary properties to object, or changing values of its properties (e.g. if some condition, like "implements Interface", is true). Now I want ask you - aren't these legit use cases? Am i doing something wrong and silly?

Comment: Yeah, you want to be using model accessors instead of what you're doing with the traits. I'll edit your answer with an example.

Comment: Take a peak at the answer now. Much easier and cleaner than using traits.

Comment: @btl Oh thanks mate. However, my intention was to use a trait + interface logic: trait is used by a *base model*, any other models extend it. Then, if some specific model should implement trait logic, write "implements SomeInterface". Next, in initSomeTrait check if model is implementing SomeInterface, and if yes, append necessary attributes and do some other stuff. Maybe I haven't made this clear enough at first, my fault. However it is out of scope of the question :) Anyway, thanks bro!

Comment: I really recommend against this practice.  Laravel has created boot methods in traits to get the functionality of a constructor without having to use a constructor. Using constructors in traits will not scale too well.