# Preventing Duplicate code in Models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two different models(ErrorLog and EntityLog) with some similar code, how can I prevent that?
EntityLog has below code:

```
class EntityLog extends Model
{
    protected const ACTION = 'action';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'entity', 'type', 'icon', 'action', 'action_detail', 'action_user_id'
    ];

    protected $with = ['action_user'];

    public function action_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ACTION_USER_ID'));
    }

    /**
     * Create Entity log
     *
     * @param $type
     * @param array $info
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function add($type, $info)
    {
        $entity = $info['entity'];
        $entity_id = $info['entity_id'] ?? '';
        $action_user_id = $info['action_user_id'] ?? auth()->user()->id ?? Config::get('constants.SYSTEM_ADMIN');
        $action_detail = $info['action_detail'] ?? '';

        switch ($type){
            case 'create':
                $icon = 'fa-plus bg-purple';
                $action = $info[self::ACTION] ?? 'created successfully';
                break;
            case 'update':
                $icon = 'fa-pencil bg-teal';
                $action = $info[self::ACTION] ?? 'updated successfully';
                break;
            case 'delete':
                $icon = 'fa-trash bg-red';
                $action = $info[self::ACTION] ?? 'deleted successfully';
                break;
            default:
                $icon = $action = 'invalid_flag';
        }

        Log::info($type.' : '.$entity.' : '.$entity_id.' : '.$action.' : '.$action_detail.' : '.$action_user_id);
        return self::create([
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ENTITY') => $entity,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ENTITY_ID') => $entity_id,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.TYPE') => $type,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ICON') => $icon,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ACTION') => $action,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ACTION_DETAIL') => $action_detail,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ACTION_USER_ID') => $action_user_id,
        ]);

    }
}
```

and class ErrorLog has below code

```
class ErrorLog extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'entity', 'type', 'icon', 'action', 'action_detail', 'action_user_id'
    ];

    protected $with = ['action_user'];

    public function action_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ACTION_USER_ID'));
    }

    /**
     * Create Error log
     *
     * @param $type
     * @param array $info
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function add($type, $info)
    {
        $entity = $info['entity'];
        $entity_id = $info['entity_id'] ?? '';
        $action_user_id = $info['action_user_id'] ?? auth()->user()->id ?? Config::get('constants.SYSTEM_ADMIN');
        $action_detail = $info['action_detail'] ?? '';

        switch ($type){
            case 'create':
                $icon = 'fa-plus bg-purple';
                $action = 'failed creating';
                break;
            case 'update':
                $icon = 'fa-pencil bg-teal';
                $action = 'failed updating';
                break;
            default:
                $icon = $action = 'invalid_flag';
        }

        Log::error($type.' : '.$entity.' : '.$entity_id.' : '.$action.' : '.$action_detail.' : '.$action_user_id);
        return self::create([
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ENTITY') => $entity,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ENTITY_ID') => $entity_id,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.TYPE') => $type,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ICON') => $icon,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ACTION') => $action,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ACTION_DETAIL') => $action_detail,
            Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ACTION_USER_ID') => $action_user_id,
        ]);

    }
}
```

I believe I can use Traits for solving this issue, but the examples am looking at are just calling simple functions from traits.

How would `$fillable`, `$with` and function `action_user` would work in case of traits.

Any help really appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LARAVEL how to change $fillable in Model from trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622923/laravel-how-to-change-fillable-in-model-from-trait)

Comment: See espacially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54904160/1331040

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to make a parent class that contains the duplicate properties and methods.

```
abstract class LogModel extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'entity', 'type', 'icon', 'action', 'action_detail', 'action_user_id'
    ];

    protected $with = ['action_user'];

    public function action_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', Config::get('constants.LOGGING.ACTION_USER_ID'));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now let your log models inherit this class:

```
class ErrorLog extends LogModel
{
    // ...
}
```